# Doubt relating to Laplace transform, eigenfunction and LTI systems

Tags: laplace-transform, convolution, eigenfunctions

The complex exponential e^(st) is an eigenfunction of Linear time invariant (LTI) systems. This implies that if the input is a complex exponential e^(st), the output will be the same complex exponential scaled by a scalar. The value of the scalar can be found from the Laplace transform of the impulse response of the system. 
Just to verify this I tried to find the output of the system by the method of convolution. The output obtained through convolution is not a signal complex exponential. It's a totally different answer obtained from eigenfunction property.
Why am I getting different answers?

[image]

Comment: $e^{st} 1_{t > 0}$ is not the same as $e^{st}$. Only the later is an eigenfunction of every LTI systems

Comment: @user1952009 silly me!!! Thanks a lot. Understood what I was doing wrong....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it converges : $$e^{st} \longrightarrow \boxed{\ h(t)\ } \longrightarrow e^{st}\ast h(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(\tau)e^{s (t-\tau)}d\tau = e^{st} H(s)$$ where $H(s) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(\tau)e^{-s\tau}d\tau$ is the (bilateral) Laplace transform of $h(t)$

Comment: H(s) should not necessarily be bilateral transform, h(t) can also be a causal signal wherein H(s) can also represent the unilateral Laplace transform. But the input signal e^(st) should be non zero for time t<0

Comment: @Danny You should really think to $\int_a^\infty h(t) e^{-st}dt$ as the bilateral Laplace transform of $h(t) 1_{t >a}$ and the Fourier transform of $ h(t)  e^{-Re(s) t} 1_{t >a}$